# Github API returns another API endpoint to make another request

Tags: reactjs, github-api

I'm using github's API to get a list of my repos and then filtering them to display some specified projects. The issue I'm having is some of the data is another API endpoint that needs to be requested. I've never encountered this before. Am I suppose to make another fetch request after I get the first dataset back from the API? For instance I'm currently using this specific end point

```
https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

and here is some of the data I get back

```
archive_url: "https://api.github.com/repos/myUserName/test-repo/{archive_format}{/ref}"
archived: false
assignees_url: "https://api.github.com/repos/myUserName/test-repo/assignees{/user}"
blobs_url: "https://api.github.com/repos/myUserName/test-repo/git/blobs{/sha}"
branches_url: "https://api.github.com/repos/myUserName/test-repo/branches{/branch}"
languages_url: "https://api.github.com/repos/alenart91/test-repo/languages"
```

so now if I want the languages_url data I have to make another fetch request?

here is my current code

```
import ProjectCard from './ProjectCard.js'

class Projects extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { projects: [], name: '' }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.getProjects();
  }

  getProjects = () => {
   const token = 'private data';
   let url = 'https://api.github.com/user/repos';

   fetch(url , {
         mode: 'cors',
         headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json', 
             'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
         }})
         .then(res => {
           if (res.status === 200) {
             return res.json();
           } else {
             return res.statusText;
           }
         })
         .then( data => {

           let filteredProjects = data.filter( projectName => {
             return projectName.name == 'test-repo' || projectName.name == 'test-repo';
           })

           this.setState( {projects: filteredProjects });
         })
         .catch( err => {
           console.log(err);
         })

 }

  render() {

    const {projects} = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>

        {projects.map( projects => {
          return <ProjectCard language = {projects.language} description = {projects.description} url = {projects.html_url} name = {projects.name} />
        })}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to make another fetch request for the languages_url endpoint. Alternatively, you can use GraphQL to get the languages of a repository in a single request. See below code for the GraphQL call. Ref. [GraphQL](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/)

```
{
  repository(owner: "<<OWNER>>", name: "<<REPONAME>>") {
    name
    languages(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the proper way to make a second fetch request using plain javascript? Do I just call another function and pass the data in as a parameter at the end of the first fetch promise chain?